# Run the function only once at the same time

Tags: javascript

I have the following problem. First of all my code so far:

```
function Auktionator() {
this.versteigern = function(objekt) {
      for(var i = 1; i <=3; i++) {
         setTimeout(function(x) { return function() { console.log(objekt + " zum " + x); }; }(i), 1000*i);
     }
};}
```

Now I want that only one Auktionator object can run the function at the same time, but I don´t know, how to do it.

Comment: You need to be clearer about what you mean with `[...]can run the function at the same time[...]`  js code never runs in parallel, so the callback functions of `setTimeout` will always run in _sequence_ and not parallel.

Comment: U can specify 100 ms to each function. They ll execute together.

Comment: Ah ok now I think I understand it, if `versteigern` is called you would like to prevent that that `versteigern` can be called by another `Auktionator` until the last `setTimeout` callback was executed?

Comment: @torazaburo They already run one after another `setTimeout(..., 1000 * i)`

Comment: @t.niese yes, exactly! Sorry, for the circumstances

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep track of the number of timeouts running and use a guard clause to prevent concurrent runs.

```
function Auktionator() {
    this.versteigern = function (objekt) {
        if (Auktionator.LOCKS > 0) {
            console.log('running');
            return;
        }

        for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            Auktionator.LOCKS++;
            setTimeout(function (x) {
                return function () {                        
                    console.log(objekt + " zum " + x);
                    Auktionator.LOCKS--;
                };
            }(i), 1000 * i);
        }
    };
}

Auktionator.LOCKS = 0;

new Auktionator().versteigern()
new Auktionator().versteigern()
```

Answer (score 1):

The hacky workaround would be to add a variable `isRunning`:

```
// Static variable shared by all instance 
Auktionator.isRunning = false;
```

Then, when you start executing, you check if `Auktionator.isRunning === false`, set it to `true` and set it back to `false` when you're done.

You have a great variety of options to execute code after some async calls:
[Promises](https://www.promisejs.org/), some [libraries](https://github.com/caolan/async) or [some awesome stuff brought by ES6](https://www.npmjs.com/package/co).

Answer (score 1):

You could have a global variable

`var function_in_use = 0`

and then add

`function_in_use = 1` at the very beginning of the function's contents and add `function_in_use = 0` immediately before the return statement.  You could then wrap the entire contents in an `if` statement: `if (!function_in_use) { ...`.

I don't know if this would suit your particular needs.  This would be similar to how `#import "filename"` statements work in the C language.